# Multiple forms in the same view !!! Blank page SLIM 3 psr-4

Tags: php, slim

I have four form on the same page.
I can't have two routes in post for the same view... 
To validate the data, I created a route in post with conditions inside and I created hidden inputs in each form.

and in my route ->

```
$app->post('/settings', function($request, $response) use($app){
        $inf = $request->getParam('inf');  // check value of input hidden 
        if($inf == '1'){
            UserInfoController::class  . ':postChangeInfo';
        }
        else if ($inf == '2'){
            PasswordController::class  . ':postChangePassword';
        }
       else if ($inf == '3'){

        }});
```

So when i submit, i have a blank page with status 200 !!! i don't understand ...

So after test when I do this it works but It takes all form from my page and not the one I want

```
$app->post('/settings',  PasswordController::class  . ':postChangePassword';)
```

Please help me

Comment: You basically just doing string concatenation.

Comment: Ok i understand , it understands it in string and not in call of the controller. but i don't know how i call my UserInfoController for exemple

Comment: Initialize an object of the class and execute the method?